# How to manage global variables in Python

Tags: python, configuration, global-variables, data-science

I am working on a data science project which have lot of data pre-processing and neural network implementation and generate graphs as png files.Project consist of almost 30+ python scripts.
I have set of common values which i need to use globally, almost every script.

So I have created a `config.yaml` file to store the values and `util.py` file to read the `yaml` file and assign values as global variables.

**part of config.yaml**

```
config:
    input_src: "./input_data"
    data_output: "./final_output"
    tempory_src: "./tmp_files"
    neural_network_model_version: "NeuralNet_v1907"
    all_store_output: "/all_store"
    single_store_output: "/individual"
```

**util.py**

```
with open('config.yaml',encoding="utf-8_sig") as f:

    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    global input_src
    global output_src
    global model_version
    global all_store_output
    global single_store_output
    global temp_src
    config=data["config"]

    input_src=config["input_src"]
    output_src=config["data_output"]
    model_version = config["neural_network_model_version"]
    all_store_output= config["all_store_output"]
    single_store_output= config["single_store_output"]
```

when i import util file it has all global variables.

I know it is not a good practice to have lot of global variables.I need to know what is the most suitable and recommended way to manage this kind of  situation.

Comment: This is subjective: You can put all your global variables in one class and expose an instance of that class as the only global variable. That's a bit cleaner.

Comment: Or you could just use a global dictionary to store all your variables.

Comment: Extending @rdas comment, use a `singleton` design pattern.

Comment: Thank you everyone for great comments. since these configurations are changing everytime (add new configs and remove ) what is the easiest way to implement?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would probably be to put all the settings into one dictionary or data class.

Another option is to use a function to load the settings, then cache the results:

```
from functools import lru_cache

import yaml


@lru_cache()
def load_config(config_path='config.yaml'):
    with open(config_path, encoding="utf-8_sig") as f:
        data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

    # TODO: validate values and calculate related values

    print('Config loaded.')  # Just to show that it only loads once.
    return data['config']

def foo():
    config = load_config()
    print(config['input_src'])

def bar():
    config = load_config()
    print(config['data_output'])

def main():
    foo()
    bar()

main()
```

If you don't like digging into that dictionary to get all the settings, you could put all the settings into a class's properties, or write more functions to grab each setting from the main settings dictionary.